# I'm not able to plot a point at the end of a circle

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Here is my code for My Project.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[{r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2  Cos[w2 x], 
    r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}, {x, 0, t}, 
   PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> {"Moon"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Time"}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}],
  ParametricPlot[{r1 Cos[w1 x], r1 Sin[w1 x]}, {x, 0, t}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Earth"}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
    Point[{r1 Cos[w1 x], r1 Sin[w1 x]}]}]],
 {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
 {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}]
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Try replacing x with t in in your Point[...]

Comment: @banone Thanks! Is there any other way to plot point besides using `Graphics` here

Comment: You could try ListPlot. It also goes well with Show.

Comment: @banone  how to adjust the size of this point in `ListPlot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternative ways to show the moving point:

Use a single `ParametricPlot` for both curves and show the moving point using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{{r1 Cos[w1 x], r1 Sin[w1 x]},
    {r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2 Cos[w2 x], r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}}, {x, 0, t}, 
   PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Earth", "Moon"}, AxesLabel -> {"Time"}, 
   PlotStyle -> { Automatic, Red}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]}]}],
 {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
 {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01}, 
 {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use separate `ParametricPlot`s for earth and moon and use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) in the first plot to show the moving point:

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot[{r1 Cos[w1 x], r1 Sin[w1 x]}, {x, 0, t}, 
    PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotLegends -> {"Earth"}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Time"}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{t}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]], 
   ParametricPlot[{r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2 Cos[w2 x], r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}, {x, 0, t}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Moon"}, PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> Thick]],
 {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
 {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01}, 
 {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Is there a way to add `PlotLegends` for Point?

Comment: @kile, you can add styling directives (`Opacity`, `PointSize`, color, etc. )  before `Point[...]`.

Comment: I want an explaination in right side of the graph like what  `PlotLegends -> {"Earth", "Moon"}` did here. For instance, red line means Moon

Comment: `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, 
  Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]}], PlotLegends -> {"Earth"}}` is not working

Comment: @kile, that's a good question. You  can not add legends inside `Epilog`. But you can change the `PlotLegends` in `ParametricPlot` to `PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[{ColorData[97]@1, Red, Blue}, {"Earth", "Moon", 
   "third legend"}, Joined -> {True, True, False}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {None, None, "Point"}]` to get the desired result.